# Why using the command `./myFile a` `a` is intepreted as an input parameter?

Tags: command-line, executable

After compiling a program with `g++ -o myFile myFile.cpp` I used `./myFile &` to execute the program.

When using the ampersand, I understand the program is executing in the background.

Can someone direct me to the right link explaining what `./myFile a` means? I don't understand why using the command `a` is intepreted as an input parameter.

Comment: This is really a programming question rather than an Ubuntu question - see [What are the arguments to main() for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734111/what-are-the-arguments-to-main-for) for example. Bottom line: command line arguments are *made available* to your program (typically as an array `argv[]`) but it is up to *it* whether it does anything with them or not.

Comment: When the system handles `./myFile a` it stores (a pointer to) the string `a` in the `argv` array (a kernel-managed list in the user processes' address space) for the program to pick up, parse, and interpret in any way it wants. The `&` in `./myFile &` is NOT a parameter passed to the program, its handled by the shell, which parses the command and starts `./myFile` without waiting for it to finish (in the background),

Comment: @waltinator thank you for answering my question. I spent a while searching online and could not find valuable information regarding my question. Using "a" makes perfect sense. For instance the program outputs capital letter's as oppose to using "&" which outputs lower case letter's. It outputs capital letters because its using string "a" to pick up the capital letters.

Comment: You might want to check the update to my answer, I wasn't answering the question directly before.

Answer (score 6):

Re-reading your question again I think I understand what you're asking.

Whatever you type in the command prompt is interpreted by an underlying shell (if you didn't change it, Bash).

There is a number of steps Bash goes through before actually running the command:

> When the shell reads input, it proceeds through a sequence of operations. If the input indicates the beginning of a comment, the shell ignores the comment symbol (‘#’), and the rest of that line.
>
> Otherwise, roughly speaking, the shell reads its input and divides the input into words and operators, employing the quoting rules to select which meanings to assign various words and characters.
>
> The shell then parses these tokens into commands and other constructs, removes the special meaning of certain words or characters, expands others, redirects input and output as needed, executes the specified command, waits for the command’s exit status, and makes that exit status available for further inspection or processing.

Whatever is left to the right of the command delimited by any sequence of the separators contained in `$IFS`, usually  , `\t` and `\n` after Bash has went through the steps outlined above is interpreted as an argument to the program: without being technical, this means that each token is made available to the program, which can make use of it the way it wants.

More specifically what happens under the hood is that each token is passed as an argument to the `execve()` syscall which starts the program and becomes available to the program through [`argv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024202/4316166) (a pointer to a pointer to a character often included in the declaration / definition of `main()`), which the program can access in order to retrieve the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The shell processes the parameters.

That will prevent the shell from doing it:

```
./myFile '&'
```

So, the program will get & as a parameter.

Other example:

```
./myFile *
```

It'll expand the star into a whole list of the parameters - the file names of files in current directory.